# Delegate methods are not calling when using separate thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have used below code for do a synchronization with web server. It is working but UI freeze for a moment becasue  getUnsyncTicketsFromServer method calling in main queue. I tried to do it in separate queue. Then it doesn't call delegate methods(requestReturnedData).

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:320.0 target:self selector:@selector(syncTickets) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)syncTickets{

   [self sendUnsyncedTickets];

   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 6 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 6 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [self getUnsyncTicketsFromServer];
       });
   });


}    

-(void)requestReturnedData:(NSData *)data{

 }
```

edit --

```
-(void)getUnsyncTicketsFromServer{

    ServiceConnector *serviceConnector = [[ServiceConnector alloc] init];
    serviceConnector.delegate = self;
    [serviceConnector getTicketsFromServer];
    dataMethod = @"get";

}
```

Comment: Where do you call requestReturnedData? Where do you set delegate?

Comment: @trick Can you check the edit.

Comment: Try running the async stuff on that separate thread and calling the delegate method by running `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...`

Comment: Why u r not using NSURLConnection???

Comment: Instead of `dispatch_after` use `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_sync` pair.

Comment: @Kanan i used NSURLConnection inside serviceConnector

Answer (score 3):

```
@implementation YourClass () {
    ServiceConnector *_serviceConnector;
}

...

-(void)getUnsyncTicketsFromServer {
    _serviceConnector = [[ServiceConnector alloc] init];
    _serviceConnector.delegate = self;
    [_serviceConnector getTicketsFromServer];
    dataMethod = @"get";
}
```

If you are using arc, I think your serviceConnector must be getting released, so store the object as an instance variable.